# ASP.NET MVC for Web/Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I'm looking forward to develop an ASP.NET MVC website based on  HTML 5 and jQuery that targets Web Browsers and Mobiles (Android + iPhones)

Is there any specific handling needed from the development point of view to target Browsers and mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://jquerymobile.com/ for handling jquery based interfaces.

Also have a look at http://www.modernizr.com/

Comment: Does this assume, I use jquerymobile to build the website and that way it opens on browsers and mobiles?

Comment: jquerymobile does work on both mobile browsers and computer browsers,the interface will just resize to the size of the screen. if you want to switch rendering between mobile device and browser you will need to detect that and render alternate html.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I noticed that in ASP.NET MVC apps, we can have views for both Desktop Browsers and Mobile browsers. I can see double work here, or just use jquerymobile to deliver same interface for both Desktop and Mobile browsers. Are there recommendations out there?